# Android How to set margin top on table using itext

Tags: android, itext

I created an android application with export pdf option and use itext plugin for creating pdf documents. I want to set table margin-top attribute because it shows on top of the document. Should I add paragraph between logo and table or is there  other solution?

Here is my code:

```
private static void createTable(Document document)
        throws BadElementException {
    try {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);

        // t.setBorderColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        // t.setPadding(4);
        // t.setSpacing(4);
        // t.setBorderWidth(1);


        PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Col2"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        c1.setFixedHeight(20);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Col2"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        c1.setFixedHeight(20);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Col3"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        c1.setFixedHeight(20);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Col4"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        c1.setFixedHeight(20);
        table.addCell(c1);

        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Col5"));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        c1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        c1.setFixedHeight(20);
        table.addCell(c1);
        table.setHeaderRows(1);

        table.addCell("1.0");
        table.addCell("1.1");
        table.addCell("1.2");
        table.addCell("1.3");
        table.addCell("1.4");

        table.addCell("2.0");
        table.addCell("2.1");
        table.addCell("2.2");
        table.addCell("2.3");
        table.addCell("2.4");

        document.add(table);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following methods to separate one table from the rest of the content:

```
    myTable.setSpacingBefore(10);
    myTable.setSpacingAfter(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to Feb - 2021 with iText7**

You can use the `margin` property:

```
myTable.setMarginTop(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Version 5.5.13.3

```
myTable.SpacingBefore = (7f);
```